# Special badges for chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, chat

Is there some plans for special badges for chat?

Comment: Do you have any ideas on what kind of things might be awarded badges in the chat?

Comment: Being chatty???

Comment: Adding a fav, having a fav reach more than X votes. Sending X messages, Creating X channels...

Comment: Is it friday already?

Comment: Chatterbox - 10,000 chat posts with zero flags :)

Comment: @waffles: Make that "Wibbler" (wibble [UK] 1. n.,v. Commonly used to describe chatter, content-free remarks or other essentially meaningless contributions to threads in newsgroups.)

Comment: anti-badge: 10 messages flagged spam/offensive

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is now the Talkative bronze badge, mostly to publicize chat per-site. See the badge page for more details.

Answer (score 16):

I hope not.  Keep the third place out of the rep race IMHO.  Incentivizing it just seems like a good way to shift the focus off of what it's actually for, and might bring people to it for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 6):

How about adding just one easy bronze badge for chat? It draws some attention to existence of chat feature but doesn't require anything massive to achieve.

`[Chatter]` - Posted at least one message to chat

Comment: Agree now done!

Answer (score 4):

We don't want to encourage discussions too much, I believe. After all, the core of SOFU is Q&A, and too much discussion in a separate site can scatter knowledge beyond the ideal point.

Giving badges for using the chat would encourage people that don't want to use the chat to use it, resulting in people that don't give a flying cow about the discussions at hand, resulting in a far lower S/N ratio.